# how to fix missing server.js / "script":{"start": ""} of package.json

Tags: npm, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to solve the path error in package.json. How do I set the path correctly? Is it a typo or is the server.js missing in the project-folder?

1. npm install -> no error
2. npm start (within project folder) -> error showed(since I am not an expert on solving problems) I looked at the error and searched for all the possible solutions to this error.I tried npm install -g to see if it would solve the problem (which it did for some people, but no progress made).

the error is:

```
reactApp git:(master) ✗ npm start

> react_proj@1.0.0 start /home/pck/reactApp
> node './http_server.js'

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/pck/reactApp/http_server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_proj@1.0.0 start: `node './http_server.js'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react_proj@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pck/.npm/_logs/2019-04-01T15_47_30_710Z-debug.log
```

in the package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node '~/http_server.js'",
    "watch": "karma start karma.conf.js --singleRun=false",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

I also installed a package. It installed a http_server.js. I tried to link http_server.js with the package.json but had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have experimented and solved my own problem. All I had to fix was the script/path within package.json.

The beginning script was:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node '~/http_server.js'",
```

into

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ../http_server.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

Is http_server in your home directory?

Comment: yes it is. do i have to connect the package.json and http_server.js? if so how do i write the start script with out any typo?

Comment: Asking for clarifying information should not be posted as an answer. Instead ask these types of questions in the comments section of the post's question.